# Ionic 3 component javascript not refreshing after upgrading to v3

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have a problem (probably) with cache while developing an ionic 3 app. I don't know if it is connected to the lazy loading of components but I have this problem after I upgraded to v3 and enabled lazy loading... The app is in development mode and I'm running it through ionic serve... If I change something in the component's ts file the change is not reflected in the browser.. I don't have this problem with component's template (html file)... If I change something in the html template it's working fine.. Also I'm using Augury chrome extension for debugging angular 2 apps... When I click on component's source it shows me the old file...

Update:
I found out that the problem lies somewhere in the ionic serve... When I restart it I can see the changes in the browser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an issue of the `app-scripts` ([github issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1092)). As you can see in that threa, to fix it just update app-scripts to the nightly version:

`npm install @ionic/app-scripts@nightly`

Comment: I get this error when I try to update app-scripts: webpack@3.2.0 - UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY ajv@5.2.2..
npm WARN ajv-keywords@2.1.0 requires a peer of ajv@>=5.0.0 but none was installed.

Comment: If you run `ionic info` in the project folder, what do you see in the `Ionic App Scripts Version:` ?

Comment: global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.5.0
    Ionic CLI        : 3.5.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : 2.0.1-201707121621
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.2
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.5.0

System:

    Node       : v7.10.0
    OS         : Linux 4.4
    Xcode      : not installed
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
    npm        : 4.2.0

Comment: Perfect, you now have the latest version of the app-scripts :) (I have the same version installed on my end). Could you please check if the error still persists?

Comment: I tried ionic serve again and it seems it's working now... I will accept this answer... thanks